# Touch intercepted after fling

Tags: android, touch-event, nestedscrollview

Recently I am experiencing some issues with my scrollview. Touch events don't reach elements inside a scrollview after a fling has happened. After a fling has occurred I first need to tap the view once again, after that the normal behaviour is restored. I already tried lot's of workarounds like:

- Manually fire a motion event (up / down) after the fling. This works but has some serious issues, I don't have to explain why I guess since this is just the same as touching the view again but that at a certain x+y.
- Intercept touch events and always pass them to the underlying views.

But all this is quite a hassle and this seems like unwanted behaviour in the first place no?

Seems like the scrollview intercepts everything after the onfling has occured untill a new normal(no fling) up & down touch.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/fsv_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/marker"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_jobs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a scrolling view (`NestedScrollView`) containing another scrolling view (`RecyclerView`).
Sounds like trouble to me.

Why do you need such a layout?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue. NestedScrollView & RecyclerView can work together on this. You can use a custom layout behaviour in the RecyclerView. This is used when you want to scroll all content, so also the imageView or other content in your layout together with the content in the RecyclerView. Correct me if I'm wrong on this though?

Comment: A view that supports scrolling (ScrollView/RecyclerView) can hijack touch events from its children when it detects a certain touch event that looks like scrolling, I think that can cause issues when these two views fight over control of the scroll action.

Comment: If you don't really need the RecyclerView to scroll, try using a non-scrolling view like a LinearLayout.

Comment: Hmm, yeah but I still want the benefits of the RecyclerView. Just like when the toolbar first slides up with the new coordinatorlayout, after that the content (RecyclerView) needs to slide up. Same with sliding down, first all the result sin the RecyclerView need to slide down untill there is no more left (first result) than the static content on top needs to slide in.

Comment: I don't think that's the way to do it, search stackoverflow for RecyclerView headers, there are a few solutions to this.