# Better way to fix "Touch Intercepted after fling"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I had the same issue as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33414912/6356497) . 
The problem is that, after fling happens, RecyclerView children don't get touch events. It is only noticable when recyclerview reaches top or bottom.

The problem here is that after reaching the top or bottom position, recycler view scroll state still remains `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` (for 1 or 2 secs). This state means `recyclerview` has not finished a fling animation yet. And in that state simple click event only stops the "SETTLING" process. Following clicks are treated normally.

It seems buggy... Because "SETTLING" process should be over immediately when reached the top.

code from RecycleView class :

```
 if (mScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                setScrollState(SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
            }
```

I have managed to fix it with this code

```
this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            val canScrollUp = recyclerView?.canScrollVertically(-1)!!
            val canScrollDown = recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)
            if (!canScrollUp || !canScrollDown) {
                recyclerView.stopScroll()
            }

        }
    })
```

My question is 
1) Is it support library bug?
2) What is the more proper way to fix this problem? Custom listener doesn't seem so good for me.

PS: my view hierarchy is not RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. It is RelativeLayout under Appbar and viewPager with fragments.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>


<FrameLayout  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#fafafa">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another workaround to @Revaz fix, because it will fail if your child views do not fill all available space or you use PagerSnapHelper with a single page. In this cases onScrolled will never be called!

Overwrite your LayoutManager's `startSmoothScroll` routine:

```
private final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
        getContext(),
        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {

    @Override
    public void startSmoothScroll(SmoothScroller smoothScroller) {
        int[] out = mPagerSnapHelper.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(
                mLayoutManager, mPagerSnapHelper.findSnapView(mLayoutManager));
        if (out[0] == 0 && out[1] == 0) {
            // workarround "Touch Intercepted after fling”
            // no scroll needed
            MyRecyclerView.this.stopScroll();
            return;
        }
        super.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
};
```

.

```
setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Needs to be fixed in support library in my opinion!